# How to load rpt file using c# in visual studio 2010?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

Am using visual studio 2010 and trying to load a rpt file.
I have used the following code.

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load("E:\\Crystal reports docs\\Crystal Reports samples\\Crosstab report");
```

Then I used `isLoaded()` function to check whether it is loaded.

When I compile the program, it keeps on running.

Any suggestions???

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: cant get yo....can u be more specific??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the sample code  how to load a crystal report (.rpt) file that is saved on a local drive instead of embedded. The advantage to this is the program does not need to be re-compiled each time a report is modified. Also, the .rpt can be upload from the application and stored in a database and then written to file. Do not embed the .rpt file when using this method.

```
using System;using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace Report
{
    public partial class Report : Document    
    {
        public void ReportLoad()    
        {
            ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();       
            string filePath = "C:\Projects\Application\Report\CrystalReport.rpt";                
            reportDocument.Load(filePath);  
            crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument; 
        }   
    }
 }
```

Refer More about

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3312329

[How do I load external Crystal Reports (2008) files in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039607/how-do-i-load-external-crystal-reports-2008-files-in-c)

Comment: Thanks ramakrishna. i have done exactly like you said but am getting a error like name crystalReportViewer does not exist in the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
 //ADD
 string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
 reportDocument.Load(filePath);
 crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
```